# From pd.MultiIndex to multple DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

Is there a concise way of converting a MultiIndexed DataFrame to multiple DataFrames, one per each combination on the multiindex.

```py
arrays = [np.array(['bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux']),
          np.array(['one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two'])]
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 4), index=arrays)
df
>>              0         1         2         3
bar one -0.424972  0.567020  0.276232 -1.087401
    two -0.673690  0.113648 -1.478427  0.524988
baz one  0.404705  0.577046 -1.715002 -1.039268
    two -0.370647 -1.157892 -1.344312  0.844885
foo one  1.075770 -0.109050  1.643563 -1.469388
    two  0.357021 -0.674600 -1.776904 -0.968914
qux one -1.294524  0.413738  0.276662 -0.472035
    two -0.013960 -0.362543 -0.006154 -0.923061
```

I would love to extract these `DataFrame`'s:

```py
df.loc[('bar', slice(None)), :]
>>      
                       0           1            2           3
bar     one     0.965409    -1.124317   -0.634161   -0.671607
        two     -2.357019   -1.541925   0.776500    1.423822
```

More generaly, I would like to extract all dataframes from level 0 to level `n-1` on the `MultiIndex`, something like a `explode` method.

Note: You could have different sizes and values for each level.

Comment: you can create a dictionary `d = dict(tuple(df.groupby(level=0)))` , then access each key to get the df back example `d['bar']`